# Differential equations substituting list back in solution

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve some Lagrange differential equations of motion, where $L = T - U$.

How can I use the solution for each x1, x2, x3, ..., xn?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
n = 10; 
t0 = 10;
 Subscript[x, 0][t_] := 0;
 Subscript[x, n + 1][t_] := 0;
 m = 1;
 v0 = 0.1; 
  Table[Subscript[k, j] = 1, {j, 0, n + 1}]; 
ic = Table[{Subscript[x, j][0] == 0, Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][0] ==RandomReal[{-v0, v0}]}, {j, 1, n}]; 

ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
       (1/2)*Sum[Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j][t] - Subscript[x, j - 1][t])^2, 
         {j, 1, n + 1}]; 
    te[x_, t_, n_] := (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}];


lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n];

eqm[j_] := D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Subscript[x, j][t], 1}] - 
    D[D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t], 1}], {t, 1}];
```

Comment: 1) There was a question about frequencies, not exact solutions. 2) There are two types of boundary conditions with $k_0=0; 5$.

Comment: Please look at the instructions here to copy readable code from MMA: [How to copy code from MMA so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerical solution

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
n = 10; t0 = 10; Subscript[x, 0][t_] := 0; Subscript[x, n + 1][t_] := 0; m = 1; v0 = 0.1; 
  Table[Subscript[k, j] = 1, {j, 0, n + 1}]; 
ic = Table[{Subscript[x, j][0] == 0, Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][0] == 
      RandomReal[{-v0, v0}]}, {j, 1, n}]; 
ue[x_, t_, k_, n_] := 
   (1/2)*Sum[Subscript[k, j]*(Subscript[x, j][t] - Subscript[x, j - 1][t])^2, 
     {j, 1, n + 1}]; 
te[x_, t_, n_] := (1/2)*m*Sum[Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t]^2, {j, 1, n}]; 
lg[x_, t_, k_, n_] := te[x, t, n] - ue[x, t, k, n]; 
eqm[j_] := D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Subscript[x, j][t], 1}] - 
    D[D[lg[x, t, k, n], {Derivative[1][Subscript[x, j]][t], 1}], {t, 1}]; 
sol = NDSolveValue[Flatten[{Table[eqm[i] == 0, {i, 1, n}], ic}], 
   Table[Subscript[x, i][t], {i, 1, n}], {t, 0, t0}]
Plot[sol, {t, 0, t0}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: FIG1]

Calculation of frequencies for a system of 100 particles with springs of different stiffness

```
    ks1[i_] := 3 + 2*(-1)^i
ks2[i_] := 3 - 2*(-1)^i
m = 1;
omega[k_, n_] := 
 Block[{k0 = k, P = n}, 
  eq1 = -m*(x[1]'')[t] + k0*(x[0][t] - x[1][t]) - 
    5 (x[1][t] - x[2][t]);
  eqP = -m*(x[P]'')[t] + k0*(x[P + 1] - x[P][t]) - 
    5 (-x[P - 1][t] + x[P][t]);
  eqn = Table[-m*x[i]''[t] - ks1[i]*(x[i][t] - x[i - 1][t]) - 
     ks2[i]*(x[i][t] - x[i + 1][t]), {i, 2, P - 1}];
  Eq1 = Join[{eq1, eqn, eqP}] /. {x[0][t] -> 0, x[P + 1][t] -> 0};
  op = Table[x[i_][t_] := A[i]*Exp[I*om*t], {i, 1, P}];
  Eq2 = Flatten[Eq1 /. t -> 0];
  Eq = Table[Eq2[[i]] == 0, {i, 1, P}];
  matr = CoefficientArrays[Eq, Table[A[i], {i, 1, P}]];
  M = Last[Normal[matr]];
  f = Det[M];
  s = Solve[f == 0, om];
  lst = Table[N[om /. s[[i]], 10], {i, 1, Length[s]}];
  Drop[Sort[lst], P]]
```

An example of using the function `omega[]`

```
lst0 = omega[0, 100];
lst5 = omega[5, 100];
{ListPlot[Abs[lst0 - lst5], PlotRange -> All],
 ListPlot[{lst0, lst5}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Row[{"k0 = ", 0}], Row[{"k0 = ", 5}]}], 
 ListPlot[lst0, PlotLabel -> Row[{"k0 = ", 0}]], 
 ListPlot[lst5, PlotLabel -> Row[{"k0 = ", 5}]]}
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: @Alrubaie I fixed the code.